# How to group XML elements from a HttpClient stream in Flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, stream

I subscribe to an API over which I have no control which returns an XML structure. That structure can be really big and take 10+ seconds to return if pulled as a single call. I have the ability to stream it (a parameter on the API) which will return the structure in chunks. Being able to process the stream as it is read will greatly improve my app's UX.

How do I transform the response of chunks into blocks of XML?

```
    final url = Uri.parse(uri);
    final request = await HttpClient().getUrl(url);
    final response = await request.close();
    final stream = response
        .transform(utf8.decoder)         
        .transform(const xml_events.XmlEventDecoder())
        .transform(const xml_events.XmlNormalizer())
        .expand((events) => events)        
        .forEach((event) => log.info('Stream Receipt: $event'));
    }
```

This will return me the individual blocks of well-formed XML such as

```
<c>
36
</c>
```

but what I really need is for the blocks that make an object, such as

```
<a id="1">
<b name="Joe">
<c>36</c>
</b>
</a>
```

It seems like I need a `transform` method and be able to specify `<a>` as my delineation tag so that the  child elements are grouped and streamed when complete?

Comment: you need `XmlNodeCodec`, something like this: `Stream.value('<root><c>c1</c><c>c2</c><c>c3</c></root>')
.transform(XmlEventCodec().decoder.fuse(XmlNodeCodec().decoder))
.listen((nodes) {
  print(nodes);
  nodes.forEach((node) {
    node.children.forEach(print);
  });
});`

Comment: I see that this creates a new stream 1 child level deep to pull the <c> nodes from the <root>. How would I go 2 child levels deep so, from `<root><a><b></b><c>c1</c><c>c2</c><c>c3</c></a></root>` I could pull the `<c>` elements? Do I have to just know that it's the nth child, or can I specify some kind of filter to only pull `<c>` elements into the stream to listen to?

Is there any decent documentation on transform, decoder, fuse, etc? I found the Flutter/Dart docs but they're kind of terse and no real example to speak of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is a bit awkward, but does what you need in a single stream using only simple operators:

```dart
input
    .transform(const XmlEventDecoder())
    .transform(const XmlNormalizer())
    .expand((events) => events)
    // skip to the start of the container
    .skipWhile((event) => !(event is XmlStartElementEvent && event.name == 'root'))
    // skip over the container element
    .skip(1)
    // consume until the end of the container
    .takeWhile((event) => !(event is XmlEndElementEvent && event.name == 'root'))
    // create a forest of sub-trees
    .map((event) => [event])
    .transform(const XmlNodeDecoder())
    .expand((elements) => elements)
    // filter out the text elements between the sub-trees
    .where((element) => element is XmlElement)
    // do something with the sub-trees
    .listen((element) => ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments - this helps a great deal. Is there any way to 'take n elements' at a time to trigger the .listen event? If the call returns 1,000 entries, I'd like to process them 100 at a time over 10 batched. If 750 returned, I do 7 batches of 100 and then drain the last 50. I'm adding markers to a Google Map and redrawing with each listen event is just too much.

Comment: Managed to achieve the above by placing the results into a List<T>. When the List.length > 100 then I copy that list into another and pass it along for Streaming to my 'external listener'. Clear the current List and continue. Clunky, but works.