# Parse a huge (3Gb) XML in Dart/Flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, xml-parsing

I have a site from which I'm receiving a huge XML file.
I need to parse it to 2 classes in Dart.

XML (part of it):

```
<fb-updates xmlns:l="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" timestamp="2018-04-19 11:33:14">
    <updated-book id="32498526" created="2018-04-18 16:35:49" last_release="2018-04-18 16:35:49" updated="2018-04-18 16:35:49" valid_till="2018-12-31" valid_from="2013-01-01" size="579411" sent_by_name="nvcvet@gmail.com" sent_by_id="9351951" must_import="0" options="0" price="0.90" you_can_sell="0" allow_read="0" allow_sell="0" has_trial="0" allow_full_free="0" public_domain="0" show_card="0" contract_author="9339265" contract_title="АСТ" subject_id="44580" external_id="b4854f32-430a-11e8-9a05-0cc47a52085c" cover="jpg" type="0" adult="16" file_parts="6" available="-1" available_date="2018-04-18 16:18:02" copyright_read_online="1" contract_ends="2018-12-31" udk="821.111-312.4" art_cover="jpg" lvl="2" sell_open="0" can_preorder="0" litex="1" chars="46369" images="1" drm="0" publisher="АСТ" date_written_s="1969" date_written_d="1969-01-01" lang="ru" src_lang="en" cover_h="1960" cover_w="1400" art_cover_w="1400" art_cover_h="1960" lang3="rus" src_lang3="eng" status="approved" rating="6030" url="" inapp_price="0.90">
        <files>
            <file size="579409" type="fb2.zip"/>
            <file size="51846" type="html"/>
            <file size="583471" type="html.zip"/>
            <file size="47604" type="txt"/>
            <file size="20832" type="txt.zip"/>
            <file size="623059" type="rtf.zip"/>
            <file size="663336" type="a4.pdf"/>
            <file size="708752" type="a6.pdf"/>
            <file size="447161" type="mobi.prc"/>
            <file size="1474324" type="epub"/>
            <file size="590189" type="ios.epub"/>
            <file size="578047" type="fb3"/>
        </files>
        <book-title title="Наследство Боксдейла"/>
        <annotation>
            <p>
            «– Видишь ли, мой дорогой Адам, – мягко объяснял каноник, прохаживаясь с главным суперинтендентом Дэлглишем под вязами возле своего пасторского дома, – как бы нам ни было кстати это наследство, оно не принесет мне радости, если моя приемная бабушка Элли получила в свое время эти деньги недостойным способом.
            </p>
            <p>
            Каноник имел в виду, что они с женой не смогут воспользоваться пятьюдесятью тысячами фунтов, оставленными им его приемной бабушкой Элли, если шестьдесят семь лет назад она отравила своего престарелого мужа мышьяком, чтобы получить их. Поскольку в 1902 году это обвинение было снято с тетушки Элли судом, который, по мнению ее хемпширских соседей, в качестве публичного зрелища мог состязаться с церемонией коронации, щепетильность каноника казалась не совсем уместной…»
            </p>
        </annotation>
        <authors>
            <author id="dc3b5610-2a80-102a-9ae1-2dfe723fe7c7">
                <subject_id>44580</subject_id>
                <url>fillis-dzheyms/</url>
                <first-name>Филлис Дороти</first-name>
                <middle-name/>
                <last-name>Джеймс</last-name>
                <full-name-rodit>Филлис Дороти Джеймс</full-name-rodit>
                <lvl>2</lvl>
                <relation>0</relation>
            </author>
            <author id="e4f1d9b0-2a80-102a-9ae1-2dfe723fe7c7">
                <subject_id>44696</subject_id>
                <url>i-doronina/</url>
                <first-name>Ирина</first-name>
                <middle-name>Яковлевна</middle-name>
                <last-name>Доронина</last-name>
                <full-name-rodit>Ирины Дорониной</full-name-rodit>
                <lvl>1</lvl>
                <relation>1</relation>
            </author>
            <author id="c9a05514-1ce6-11e2-86b3-b737ee03444a">
                <subject_id>2835185</subject_id>
                <url>raznoe-4/</url>
                <first-name>Литагент</first-name>
                <middle-name/>
                <last-name>АСТ</last-name>
                <full-name-rodit/>
                <lvl>2</lvl>
                <relation>2</relation>
            </author>
        </authors>
        <genres>
            <genre title="зарубежные детективы" id="5219" bisac="FIC022000" master="1"/>
            <genre title="классические детективы" id="5261" bisac="FIC022000"/>
        </genres>
        <relations>
            <related uuid="BA8F3184-9049-4EAF-A47B-9D711D9135DC" relation="6" type="0"/>
        </relations>
        <copyrights>
            <copyright id="9339265" title="АСТ" percent="100.00"/>
        </copyrights>
        <livelib livelib_id="1001260109" rating="7.263" avg_mark="3.8246" count_readers="2271" widget_url="book/1100906/ratingbutton2015.png" widget_url2="book/1100906/ratingbuttonwhite.png" mark_1="2" mark_2="5" mark_3="48" mark_4="78" mark_5="885"/>
    </updated-book>
    <updated-book id="32523047" created="2018-04-19 09:14:23" last_release="2018-04-19 09:14:23" updated="2018-04-19 09:14:23" valid_till="2021-11-01" valid_from="2016-11-01" size="5653231" sent_by_name="sabanova" sent_by_id="9355626" must_import="0" options="68" price="5.99" you_can_sell="0" allow_read="0" allow_sell="0" has_trial="0" allow_full_free="0" public_domain="0" show_card="64" contract_author="9356032" contract_title="Эксмо" subject_id="44790" external_id="0a6e477f-4398-11e8-aa6b-0cc47a520474" cover="jpg" type="1" adult="0" file_parts="0" available="-1" available_date="2018-04-19 09:11:16" copyright_read_online="0" contract_ends="2021-02-12" art_cover="jpg" lvl="4" sell_open="0" can_preorder="0" litex="0" chars="4368" drm="0" publisher="" lang="ru" cover_h="1500" cover_w="1071" art_cover_w="1071" art_cover_h="1500" lang3="rus" status="approved" url="" inapp_price="5.99">
        <files>
            <group value="Ознакомительный фрагмент. MP3" group_id="1">
                <file id="37754271" size="5653231" filename="Sample.mp3" seconds="4368" mime_type="audio/mpeg" file_description="MP3"/>
            </group>
            <group value="Стандартное качество. MP3" group_id="5">
                <file id="37754255" size="5669432" filename="01.mp3" seconds="354" mime_type="audio/mpeg" file_description="MP3"/>
                <file id="37754231" size="14099251" filename="02.mp3" seconds="880" mime_type="audio/mpeg" file_description="MP3"/>
                <file id="37754263" size="11474467" filename="03.mp3" seconds="716" mime_type="audio/mpeg" file_description="MP3"/>
                <file id="37754215" size="5472573" filename="04.mp3" seconds="341" mime_type="audio/mpeg" file_description="MP3"/>
                <file id="37754239" size="24781451" filename="05.mp3" seconds="1548" mime_type="audio/mpeg" file_description="MP3"/>
                <file id="37754247" size="8470594" filename="06.mp3" seconds="529" mime_type="audio/mpeg" file_description="MP3"/>
            </group>
            <group value="Мобильная версия. MP4" group_id="19">
                <file id="37754223" size="31707503" filename="Sovetnik_Po_Kulture.m4b" seconds="4366" mime_type="audio/m4b" file_description="M4B-файл"/>
            </group>
        </files>
        <book-title title="Советник по культуре"/>
        <annotation>
            <p>
            Николай Стверцов прибыл на планету Ниона в качестве советника по культуре посольства Земной Федерации. Он должен сыграть важную роль в межгалактическом проекте «Восхождение». Проект призван помочь пяти расам Нионы достичь более высокого уровня развития. Но, узнав о страшной тайне изготовления шейота, который является главным предметом экспорта с отсталой планеты, Стверцов начинает сомневаться в правильности политики Земной Федерации на Нионе…
            </p>
        </annotation>
        <authors>
            <author id="ea92d3b4-2a80-102a-9ae1-2dfe723fe7c7">
                <subject_id>44790</subject_id>
                <url>aleksey-kalugin/</url>
                <first-name>Алексей</first-name>
                <middle-name>Александрович</middle-name>
                <last-name>Калугин</last-name>
                <full-name-rodit>Алексея Калугина</full-name-rodit>
                <lvl>4</lvl>
                <relation>0</relation>
                <exid>1-00000025829</exid>
            </author>
            <author id="556f2637-8bde-11e6-9c73-0cc47a1952f2">
                <subject_id>10117645</subject_id>
                <url>audioagent-litres-chtec-pablik/</url>
                <first-name>Аудиоагент</first-name>
                <middle-name/>
                <last-name>ЛитРес Чтец</last-name>
                <full-name-rodit>Аудиоагента ЛитРес Чтец</full-name-rodit>
                <lvl>1</lvl>
                <relation>2</relation>
            </author>
            <author id="a4d115a3-a4f2-11e6-a11d-0cc47a5203ba">
                <subject_id>10389074</subject_id>
                <url>raznoe-10389074/</url>
                <first-name>Аудиоагент</first-name>
                <middle-name/>
                <last-name>1 редакция-прямой договор</last-name>
                <full-name-rodit/>
                <lvl>1</lvl>
                <relation>2</relation>
            </author>
            <author id="f703f2a3-24cc-11e7-b088-0cc47a52085c">
                <subject_id>11119920</subject_id>
                <url>dumanskiy-andrey/</url>
                <first-name>Андрей</first-name>
                <middle-name/>
                <last-name>Думанский</last-name>
                <full-name-rodit>Думанского Андрея</full-name-rodit>
                <lvl>1</lvl>
                <relation>2</relation>
            </author>
            <author id="f703f2a3-24cc-11e7-b088-0cc47a52085c">
                <subject_id>11119920</subject_id>
                <url>dumanskiy-andrey/</url>
                <first-name>Андрей</first-name>
                <middle-name/>
                <last-name>Думанский</last-name>
                <full-name-rodit>Думанского Андрея</full-name-rodit>
                <lvl>1</lvl>
                <relation>6</relation>
            </author>
        </authors>
        <genres>
            <genre title="научная фантастика" id="5073" bisac="FIC028020"/>
            <genre title="социальная фантастика" id="5078" bisac="FIC028000"/>
        </genres>
        <relations>
            <related uuid="76316fbc-2c44-102b-839c-b3fddb510218" relation="8" type="0"/>
        </relations>
        <copyrights>
            <copyright id="9354189" title="ЛитРес: чтец" percent="26.00"/>
            <copyright id="9354794" title="Эксмо" percent="50.00"/>
            <copyright id="9356032" title="Думанский Андрей" percent="100.00"/>
        </copyrights>
    </updated-book>
    <removed-book id="24261892" uid="fc3ba230-4753-11e7-b2fb-0cc47a52085c" removed="2018-04-19 10:34:13"/>
</fb-updates>
```

So I have 2 classes to implement, one for updated-book and one for removed-book.

The classes are following:

RemovedBook is simple:

```
class RemovedBook {
    RemovedBook({
        this.id,
        this.uid,
        this.removed,
    });

    String id;
    String uid;
    DateTime removed;
}
```

UpdatedBook class is more complicated, but it's not the scope of the question.

The question is, how can I parse the XML response with Dart Xml package.

They have description of stream function, but I cannot realize how to get my classes from it.

```
final url = Uri.parse('http://ip-api.com/xml/');
final request = await httpClient.getUrl(url);
final response = await request.close();
final stream = response
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(const XmlEventDecoder())
    .transform(const XmlNormalizer())
    .expand((events) => events)
    .forEach((event) => print(event));
```

So, how can I get my classes from the stream ?

Comment: And I also need to keep a timestamp from the 1st line of XML stream.

Comment: Do you have to parse it from the stream? Why not receive the whole response and parse it using `XmlDocument.parse(String s)`?

Comment: It' huge, about 3GB, I can get out of RAM. And I also want to know how to get data from stream for the future projects.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in [How to group XML elements from a HttpClient stream in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741871/how-to-group-xml-elements-from-a-httpclient-stream-in-flutter) explains how to convert a stream of events (bounded by the conditions in `skipWhile` and `takeWhile`) to sub-trees of nodes (using `XmlNodeDecoder`).

In this case it is a bit more complicated: we need to enter/exit the skipping/taking parts multiple times. Unfortunately I am unaware of how to do that with Dart Streams in an elegant way (maybe easier using some of the Rx extensions?), but as of [xml 4.4.0](https://pub.dev/packages/xml/versions/4.4.0) you can write:

```dart
response
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .toXmlEvents()
    .selectSubtreeEvents((event) =>
        event.name == 'updated-book' || event.name == 'removed-book')
    .toXmlNodes()
    .flatten()
    .where((node) => node is XmlElement)
    .cast<XmlElement>()
    .map((element) {
      if (element.name.qualified == 'removed-book') {
        return RemovedBook(
            id: element.getAttribute('id'),
            ...
        ));
      } else {
        ...
      }
    })
    .forEach(print);
```

While it is definitely possible to read and process such data on a mobile device with Flutter, you might want to consider preprocessing such large amount of data on a more powerful device beforehand.

Comment: I'm writing in clear Dart, so I just need to get data from XML and put it to my Firebase, so no Flutter and mobile devices here ))